# Optimize contains query of numbers to exact match query

Tags: math, optimization, aerospike

I am looking to optimize my contains query. I have a pipe separated list of numbers in one of my Aerospike bins(columns) something like `234|235|236|`

These numbers may vary from `1 to 2^14`

Currently I am applying a `contains query` to find `235|` in this column but it is getting slow. Is there any Math or any strategy I can apply to convert this contains query to an exact match??

TIA,

Karan

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using a List type for this bin? You can then build a secondary index on the List values (indextype = LIST, type=NUMERIC)and get all records that match the value of interest in the list using a secondary index query.